# PHP file_get_contents after php has evaluated

Tags: php, import, fopen, require

I know how to use file_get_contents and fopen etc, but when I do it to one of my own file, I get the literal string, meaning, the code is not preprocessed! How can i import text from a file without using require etc. because I want to store the value into a string

Comment: file_get_contents should work.  Post the code that is having issues.

Comment: So you have code in a file and you want to execute it and do something with the result?

Comment: I think he is saying he wants to get the text that the script outputs.  Why can't you use require/include?

Comment: Nevermind, I understand what you mean now.  Use chigley's solution

Answer (score 10, accepted):

See examples #5 and #6 on [the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php). Taken straight from there:

```
$string = get_include_contents('somefile.php');

function get_include_contents($filename) {
    if (is_file($filename)) {
        ob_start();
        include $filename;
        $contents = ob_get_contents();
        ob_end_clean();
        return $contents;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: DUDE I LOVE YOU THIS WORKED MAGICALLY