# Adding included file contents to a variable

Tags: php

I am trying to add a the contents of an include file to a variable.

For example I have a variable called $form:

```
$form = 'Hello world';
$form .= include('sidebar.inc.php');
```

Is there another way to do this? Because the method noted above is causing me some problems...

Comment: You can do that assuming the included file uses a `return` at the end.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of using `include()`, you can use `file_get_contents()` to store it in a variable:

```
$form = file_get_contents('sidebar.inc.php');
```

That won't parse the PHP before storing it in your variable so another option is a solution posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3850435/php-file-get-contents-after-php-has-evaluated) from the [include](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) manual:

```
$string = get_include_contents('sidebar.inc.php');

function get_include_contents($filename) {
   if (is_file($filename)) {
     ob_start();
     include $filename;
     $contents = ob_get_contents();
     ob_end_clean();
     return $contents;
   }
   return false;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
ob_start();
include('sidebar.inc.php');
$var = ob_get_flush();
```

file_get_contents('sidebar.inc.php') does not parse php files. (your IF LOOP ELSE stuff)

Answer (score 0):

```
$form = file_get_contents('sidebar.inc.php');
```