# PHP syntax error, unexpected 'echo' (T_ECHO)

Tags: php, variables, echo

A file theme-style.php contains PHP codes and I am trying to output that to a CSS file. when i try to use `echo` with `file_gets_content` i am getting error code  `syntax error, unexpected 'echo' (T_ECHO)`

if I don't use `echo` **it just outputs all PHP codes to CSS**. where i am making mistake?

here is the code I am using:-

```
$fp = fopen('mstyle.css', 'w');
$mee = echo file_get_contents(get_template_directory() . '/css/theme-style.php');
fwrite($fp, $mee);
fclose($fp);
```

Comment: `echo` is a command for sending content directly to the output. You can't assign the result of echo. If you want to assign the variable, just assign it...no need for echo.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need echo

```
$fp = fopen('mstyle.css', 'w');
$mee = file_get_contents(get_template_directory() . '/css/theme-style.php');
fwrite($fp, strip_tags($mee));
fclose($fp);
```

file_get_contents returns directly à string

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php

and echo is not used to assign a variable but to send st to the output device

strip_tags is used to remove html tags and php code is inside html tag.

Comment: This doesn't fully answer the question - this will not evaluate the contents of the `theme-style.php` file and as stated in the question it will just "output all php code to css"

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3850454/12446017) for a similar question should get the evaluated output of the given file ready to pass into the `fwrite`

Comment: it just outputs all the PHP code. i already mentioned in my question

Comment: Correct but can you give an example of what you want (to remove)

Comment: the file contains a combination of PHP and css. the output of the file is the only CSS. i want to write that to a separate css file

Comment: php is coded between html tags you can use strip_tags to remove them, I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Using the output buffer ob_start will solve the problem and give the proper output.

```
$string = get_include_contents(get_template_directory() . '/css/theme-style.php');

function get_include_contents($filename) {
    if (is_file($filename)) {
        ob_start();
        include $filename;
        $contents = ob_get_contents();
        ob_end_clean();
        return $contents;
    }
    return false;
}
$fp = fopen('mstyle.css', 'w');
fwrite($fp, $string);
fclose($fp);
```