# Get .php file locally using curl

Tags: php, curl

I'm using `curl` in PHP to return the content of a PHP file. I want to do this locally because I will be accessing multiple PHP files during the same script, so it would be faster to open the file directly.

However, I want to be able to push parameters into the PHP files (treat them exactly as PHP files on the web, but grabbing them locally), as I want to push parameters into the scripts which will be generating additional dynamic content when I grab it.

Is this possible to do if I call the files locally? I've tried using the file:///, calling the file directly, but this won't run the PHP code found in these files.

Any ideas?

**edit**

Sorry for the confusion:
-This is currently running on a webserver, and I am currently calling http:// (and not file:///) so the PHP contained in those files can be executed. However, I find this to be slow because I'm generating multiple curl() calls that are essentially calling the server itself multiple times.

Comment: use `http://` ? like `http://localhost/file.php` ?

Comment: What is the reason to not just use `require` / `include`?

Comment: You would have to accesses it like you would through the webserver. There is however, rarely a good reason to do this. If you have the files locally, why not include the directly?

Comment: @Peter, I'm currently doing this, but it's slow, because it's essentially establishing a new connection for every page (via curl), no?

Comment: I'm using curl because I need to save the content of each PHP file in variable, as I'm pushing them in a PDF generator. The idea is to have a library of .PHP files that contain the static content of pages to be pushed to the PDF, with a couple of dynamic strings passed along to them from my main script calling the curls.

Comment: This is what we have functions for..

Comment: If you are going to use CURL, you need to send everything via an http connection. Which essentially means that you will create a new connection/request for every curl include.

Comment: You can use include and control the output with output buffering. You may need to fix some variables that are required by the script, but it is a preferable way to capture the output.

Answer (score 4):

you can do trick like:

```
function php_to_string($php_file, $new_GET = false, $new_POST = false) {
    // replacing $_GET, $_POST if necessary
    if($new_GET) {
        $old_GET = $_GET;            
        $_GET = $new_GET;
    }
    if($new_POST) {
        $old_POST = $_POST;            
        $_POST = $new_POST;
    }
    ob_start();
    include($php_file);
    // restoring $_GET, $_POST if necessary
    if(isset($old_GET)) {
       $_GET = $old_GET;
    }
    if(isset($old_POST)) {
       $_POST = $old_POST;
    }
    return ob_get_clean();
}

$content = php_to_string('my_file.php');
$content = php_to_string('my_file.php', Array('id'=>23)); // http://localhost/my_fie.php?id=23
```

But please mind it may overwrite your existing variables, causing bugs (for example duplicate defines) etc. so you may use [sandbox solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/324726/is-there-a-way-to-execute-php-code-in-a-sandbox-from-within-php)

Answer (score 1):

I believe you would want to set up a web server (e.g. Apache) on your local machine so you can go to `http://localhost/script.php?param1=foo&param2=bar` instead of `file:///path/to/script.php`. The difference is that when you do `file:///`, the files are just *opened*, but if you go through Apache, the scripts are actually *executed*.

As for passing arguments to your scripts, use the query string for that (e.g. `?param1=foo`, etc.).

I don't know why you're doing what you're doing, but hopefully that helps you do it.

Comment: Thanks, I'm actually running this on a web server (sorry didn't mention this). I'm currently running is as http://, but this is generally slow because I'm calling multiple PHP pages in order to get their content one by one. Essentially I'm looking for the speed of file:/// while still getting the execution and parameterization of http.