# How I can sandbox a PHP script?

Tags: php

Is there a way to safely run a user-supplied PHP script?
I think I must disable:

- fopen and all other file related functions
- exec and other way to execute a command
- curl
- mail to prevent spam

Is that enough?
How I can disable all that stuff(only for that script, not for my scripts)?

Thanks for help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to execute php code in a sandbox from within php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/324726/is-there-a-way-to-execute-php-code-in-a-sandbox-from-within-php) and many others

Comment: @Juhana No, that question is about an environment sandbox, while mine is about a security sandbox for user supplied scripts.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at Runkit_Sandbox: http://php.net/manual/en/runkit.sandbox.php

> Instantiating the Runkit_Sandbox class creates a new thread with its own scope and program stack. Using a set of options passed to the constructor, this environment may be restricted to a subset of what the primary interpreter can do and provide a safer environment for executing user supplied code.

Comment: Thanks, can you also suggest a list of functions/classes I must disable to prevent any interaction with the host machine?

Comment: Please have a look at all possible security attacks and then disable those functions which you would not need. http://php.net/manual/en/security.cgi-bin.attacks.php

Comment: Actually, have a complete look of all security issues in php. http://php.net/manual/en/security.php

Comment: And don't forget to choose my answer if it helps you

Comment: Well, links you gave me are talking of external attacks, while in my case there is a malicious script I have to run, in my question there is a list of things I think I must disable, but I am sure I has forgotten something...